# How to build Apache httpd cspnonce module for Windows?

Tags: windows, apache, build

I try to build cspnonce module for Apache httpd server for Windows. The repository is from https://github.com/wyday/mod_cspnonce. This is the first time I try to compile an Apache module by myself.

I put the source files in the Apache 2.4.51 source file root as the readme file mentioned, then download and put apr, apr-uitl in src-lib folder, as the "additional include directories" of the project implies. But Visual Studio told me that it can't find os.h, ap_config_layout.h, apr.h, <string.h>, Windows.h, etc.

Do I need to do something first with Apache source code? For example, make ap_config_layout.h based on ap_config_layout.h.in? I have no clue why there are so many missing include files.

Comment: Did you check this guide?(https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/win_compiling.html)

Comment: Thanks Bart. I followed that guide but with no success. I got lots of error in project apr, it seems like VC can not find many include files, even <stdio.h> <ctype.h>. I installed VS 2003 and VS 2017 on the same computer, maybe that's the cause? I just tryig to figure out how to set the include and library path properly...